# Copy a Magento package

Tags: migration, package

i'm new to Magento and i'd like to copy a complete Magento Storeview (full package incl. the theme) to another server. The Data doesnt matter nor the options just the design.

I already copied the template and skin folders:

/app/design/frontend//...
/skin/frontend//...

But the view isnt as expected. Did i forgot something?

Comment: Magento Version is: 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the theme.
Copy the folder

> skin//frontend/yourthemepkg/

and

> app/design/frontend/yourthemepkg

Paste this to new location following folder structure.
Apply the theme from admin pannel.

> System->configuration->design

then just clear the cache.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i just want to copy a Theme not the full magento shop nor store with it's data.

Comment: @roccr edited the answer, you can edit the question,  as per your above comment